# Why Mongoose createdAt / updatedAt output a wrong time(only return current time not the time in db)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The Data stored in my db is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58da135cfc80bc44f7653fd4"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-03-28T08:00:59.541Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-03-28T07:40:12.742Z"),
    "name" : "hello",
    "delete" : false,
    "enabledPlugins" : [ 
        ObjectId("58c24f65b363502f907738f9")
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

My Schema Like:

```
const mongoose = require('./db');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const templateSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, index: true, unique: true },
  enabledPlugins: [
    { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }
  ],
  delete: { type: Boolean, default: false }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

const Template = mongoose.model('Template', templateSchema);

module.exports = Template;
```

But When I want to get templates, I get the wrong timestamp:

```
exports.getAllTemplates = async function() {
  return await Template.aggregate(
    { $match: { delete: false } },
    { $project: { id: '$_id', _id: 0, name: 1, enabledPlugins: 1, createdAt: 1 } }
  );
};
```

The result like :

```
[
  {
    "createdAt": "2017-03-28T17:04:30.502+08:00",
    "name": "hello",
    "enabledPlugins": [
      "58c24f65b363502f907738f9"
    ],
    "id": "58da135cfc80bc44f7653fd4"
  }
]
```

And I found before toJSON, the output has been wrong. I don't use any plugins. All the date type has the same problem.

Comment: I  think it's time format issue. Can you check  `createdAt.toUTCString()`  after getting response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, the problem is that I rewrite `Date.prototype.toISOString`